# Spring XD and CDH

Tags: cloudera, spring-xd

Is Spring XD able to support Cloudera CDH?

http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs.../#using-hadoop mentions that CDH is an option. However, the xd-admin command only accepts the following arguments for the --hadoopDistro parameter: hadoop10, hadoop11, hadoop20, phd1. None of this is for CDH.

Answer (score 2):

There was recently a change made to include these options: hadoop12, hadoop20, cdh4, hdp13 and phd1

It is not in a release yet and the M3 release has the options you mentioned.

The online documentation reflects the current state of the code and will be part of the release download when we cut a new release. The release zip contains a copy of the docs as of the release.

Comment: Note that you can still benefit from CDH *now* by pulling the code from github and building from source. This is as easy as ```./gradlew dist```